# Best way to refresh my tic tac toe game with pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 95% completed my Player vs Player tic tac toe game. In the future I will add a nice AI and will set conditions for when someone wins.

Right now I'm just looking for the best way to refresh my game without having the page reload in pure JavaScript. I have a button at the bottom of my page and basically once it clicks I want whatever is on my board to be totally cleared and the game starts over.

They would click on this at the bottom of my HTML

```
<center><div id="refresh" class="fa fa-refresh faa-spin animated-hover fa-5x"></div></center>
```

Here's my tic tac toe game so far in case anyone wants to look over it :)

Trying really hard to become really good at HTML/CSS/JavaScript >< So hard!

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-animation.min.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<header>
    <h1>Tic-Tac-Toe </h1>
</header>

<body>
<!--Table for Tic Tac Toe-->
<table id="mytable" class="grid">
    <tr>
        <td id="field1" class="square"></td>
        <td id="field2" class="square v"></td>
        <td id="field3" class="square"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="field3" class="square h"></td>
        <td id="field4" class="square v h"></td>
        <td id="field5" class="square h"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="field4" class="square"></td>
        <td id="field5" class="square v"></td>
        <td id="field6" class="square"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--Refresh Icon/Start Game Over-->
<div id="refreshIcon">
    <center><div id="refresh" class="fa fa-refresh faa-spin animated-hover fa-5x"></div></center>
</div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var xTick = "../images/x-tick.png";
var oTick = "../images/o-tick.png";
var bg = null;
var counter = 0;
var memoryMove = [];
var refreshButton = document.getElementById('refresh');

var listRows = document.getElementById("mytable").rows;
/** detecting rows */
for(var i = 0; i < listRows.length;i++){
    /** detecting cells */
    for(var x = 0; x < listRows[i].cells.length; x++){
        listRows[i].cells[x].setAttribute("data-cell",i.toString()+x.toString());
        listRows[i].cells[x].addEventListener("click",function(){
            var move = this.getAttribute("data-cell");
            console.log(move);
            if (memoryMove.indexOf(move) === -1){
                memoryMove.push(move);
                if (counter === 0){
                    bg = xTick;
                } else {
                    if(counter % 2 === 0){
                        bg = xTick;
                    } else {
                        bg = oTick;
                    }
                }
                counter++;
                this.style.background="url('./images/"+bg+"') center center no-repeat";
            } else {
                alert('Stop trying to cheat!');
            }
            /** Start a new game */
            refreshButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

                // alert("Refresh Results");
            })
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use html canvas

Comment: My rubric told me to use a table :( I was looking at canvas and it was cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on clicking the refresh button just remove the background image of each `td`. Also reset your `counter` and `memoryMove`.

```
refreshButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    for (var i = 1;i <= 9;i++) {
        document.getElementById("field"+i).style.background="none";
        counter = 0;
        memoryMove = [];
    }

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated in pure javascript:

```
for (var i = 1;i <= 9;i++) {
    var fieldId = "field" + i; //ex 'field1'
    document.getElementById(fieldId).value = "";
}
```

Comment: `$("#field" + i).value = "";` for this only using an external library...????? and still use `value` rather than `val()`

Comment: jQuery is an extremely light library and is used on the majority of websites. It's not going to hinder the apps performance at all.

Comment: Just note if the OP did not include the `jquery` tag I would not reccommend giving an answer using jQuery. Eppseically when it's not necessary in this case. Since you can just do `document.getElementById(fieldId).value = ""`.